# Inverted georeferenced image as output of GDAL

Tags: qgis, python, raster, coordinate-system, gdal

I am trying to batch georeference a set of raster images using the GDAL function in python. For this, I georeferenced a raster image manually using QGIS and extracted the values of GCP as a CSV file. I then used the GCP points from the QGIS as the input and the SRC and CRC ESRI value I used was 102025. For some reason, the output is getting inverted. I tried to change the projection, modified pixel values and still, the output image is inverted.

Please find the attached code and the set of Input and Output Images.

```
# Skipping the input CSV extraction of the program (I did it using pandas data frame)

#list of GCP points
gcp_list=[]
for index, rows in modified_df.iterrows():
   gcps = gdal.GCP(rows.mapX, rows.mapY, 1, rows.pixelX, rows.pixelY )
   gcp_list.append(gcps)
   
# Set spatial reference:
sr = osr.SpatialReference()

# Projection- taken from the website of ESRI 102025
sr.ImportFromProj4("+proj=aea +lat_1=15 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=30 +lon_0=95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m no_defs") 

# Final Projection
ds = gdal.Open( output_fn, gdal.GA_Update )
wkt = ds.GetProjection()
gcpcount = ds.GetGCPCount( )

#Inversion is happening here
ds.SetGCPs( gcp_list, wkt )

#Clear the output file if it is opened anywhere else
ds=None
```

**Input Image**

[image: Input Image]

**Output Image using GDAL**

[image: GDAL Output]

**Output of QGIS**

[image: Output of QGIS]

**Projection of the GDAL output in OSM**

[image: GDAL output projection in OSM]

**GCP Points**

The value 1200 was added to all the pixel values of the Y coordinate because the pixel values were negative.

Georeferenced using ESRI: 102025 both in QGIS and GDAL.

[image: GCP points]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should multiply Y pixel coordinates by -1 instead of adding a constant value.

Sometimes software (QGIS georeferencing tool in your example) shows negative pixel coordinates (so the value decreases from top to bottom) but pixel coordinates are usually 0 at the top and increasing to the bottom of the image.